# Can I use Xamarin.Forms for creating windows phone application which will support Win 7, 8, 8.1, 10?

Tags: xamarin

I want to create windows phone application which will support Win phone 7, 8, 8.1, 10, all these 4 OS. Can I use Xamarin.Forms for this application?
If not then please suggest good option.

Comment: When you're told you need to enter more characters, the solution isn't to repeat yourself over and over, the solution is to figure out what extra information needs to be added. Read through [ask], then [edit] your question to fit that. If it seems like [ask] doesn't apply to what you want to ask, make sure that your question (a) can't be solved by a quick Google search and (b) fits with [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Windows 8.1+ is supported, Target Platforms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/installation/#Target_Platforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms Supports below platforms:

1. Android
2. iOS
3. WinPhone
4. Windows(WinRT)
5. UWP

By checking on Windows Side:

- **WinPhone**: Supports WP8 or above
- **WinRT** : Support Windows 8.1 or above
- **UWP** : Support Windows 10

Unfortunately Xamarin.Forms does not support Windows 7 and windows 8.